# cannot change a property of swift class circular Loader

Tags: ios, swift, class, properties, uicolor

I created a class in Swift to animate circle loading using this tutorial
https://www.raywenderlich.com/94302/implement-circular-image-loader-animation-cashapelayer, everything worked just fine, but when I try to change the color of the stroke in the view controller in which I want to use the class

```
class CircularLoaderView: UIView {
let circlePathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var circleRadius: CGFloat = 20.0
var strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    configure()
}

func configure() {
    progress = 0
    circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
    circlePathLayer.lineWidth = 10
    circlePathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    circlePathLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
    layer.addSublayer(circlePathLayer)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Then I set properties

```
//LoadingRing
    progressIndicatorView.removeFromSuperview()
    progressIndicatorView.frame = actionView.bounds
    progressIndicatorView.circleRadius = (recordButtonWhiteRing.frame.size.height - 10) / 2
    progressIndicatorView.progress = 0.0
    progressIndicatorView.strokeColor = UIColor.init(red: 232 / 255.0, green: 28 / 255.0, blue: 45 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
```

But the stroke still appears White instead of the needed color, Please any help!

Comment: Try `UIColor(red: 232 / 255.0,` etc. instead of `UIColor.init(`. Also, do you end up putting `progressIndicatorView` back into your visible view hierarchy at some point?

Comment: Oh, you're only calling `configure()` when your `CircularLoaderView` is *initialized*, and that's the bit that sets `circlePathLayer.strokeColor`. Changing the value of `strokeColor` after that doesn't affect your underlying `CAShapeLayer`'s values.

Comment: You'd generally implement a `didSet` on `circleRadius` and `strokeColor` such that they update the `circlePathLayer`. (I'd also recommend making `circlePathLayer` a `private` property, to keep external classes from modifying it.)

Comment: @CodyWeaver - Out of curiosity, where do you think this is missing `.CGColor`? The above looks fine. He's just not updating the layer when the view's custom property changes.

Comment: @Rob I am on mobile and couldn't see where he has it.

Answer (score 0):

The stroke's color is determined by the value of `circlePathLayer.strokeColor`, which you modify in `configure()` when an instance of your progress indicator is created -- and when your instance is created, its `strokeColor` is `UIColor.whiteColor()`.

You should either attach a listener to synchronize your view's `strokeColor` with that of its underlying `circlePathLayer`:

```
var strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
  didSet {
    circlePathLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
  }
}
```

or just use getters/setters to directly expose the important `strokeColor`.

```
var strokeColor: UIColor {
  get {
    guard let cgColor = circlePathLayer.strokeColor else {
      return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    return UIColor(CGColor: cgColor)
  }
  set (strokeColor) {
    circlePathLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
  }
}
```

(Edit: as Rob pointed out, CGColor casts are necessary to make this correct-ish.)

Comment: The shape layer's `strokeColor` is a `CGColor`, so you need `didSet { circlePathLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor }`. You need equivalent changes in your computed property example, too.

Comment: Also, if he uses the computed property approach, he might want to tweak his `configure` method (it makes little sense to set the `strokeColor` of the shape layer to a value which is just computed to be the `strokeColor` of the same shape layer).